# Twilio: Dial failover on busy signal

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Scenario:

Person A calls my server. My server returns Twiml with Dial plus extra, connecting them to my client C.  Sometimes C's phone is busy, and the extra just tells A they couldn't be connected, try texting.

I want to have a failover, where the same thing happens when C is not busy, but if C is busy, A is put in a queue, as are subsequent callers.  When C's call ends, I try to connect A to C.

Is there a way of doing this with simple Twiml verbs, like dial.queue, and Redirect?  So far I've failed: I can enqueue A when C is busy, hearing hold music and all, but I've utterly failed to get A off the queue and in touch with C.  I suspect I'll need to create calls using the API, but figured I'd ask to see if the Twiml way should be doable.

I am aware that I could just throw all callers into a queue, but for business reasons I want to preserve the "ring and connect" behavior when the client is immediately available.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The bit here is getting A to start a new call once they are done with the call they are on. You could, for example, [send an SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) to A to tell them that someone is waiting in the queue. Then, when they call their Twilio number back return TwiML that [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial)s into the [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/queue).

When using the `<Queue>` TwiML, the caller will be connected to the person waiting at the front of the queue.

Alternatively, if you don't trust A to call the queue back, you could keep trying to periodically [make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) to A using the REST API and once the call connects return the same TwiML to `<Dial>` into the `<Queue>`. If the caller hangs up and the queue becomes empty before A answers the call, you can stop calling and perhaps send a message to inform A that someone called and they can choose to call them back.